# Can't sent content-length in post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, http-post

I'm trying to send python post request but when I add to headers `"Content-Length" : 67` I got the error:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader:
    Value for header {Content-Length: 67} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'int'>
```

When I tried to send as a string I just got timeout error.
I must note the content length.

This is part of the code:

```
url_enter = 'some url..'
data_login = {some data login}
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;"
              "q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "User-Agent": "some user agent",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Length": 67
    }

res = requests.post(url_enter, headers=headers, cookies=data_login, timeout=7)
print(res.headers)
```